# How to Remove Trailing Comma

Tags: php

I am trying to remove the trailing comma from my php statement

```
<?php foreach( $speaker_posts as $sp ): ?>
{
    "@type" : "person",
    "name" : "<?php the_field('name_title', $sp->ID); ?>",
    "sameAs" : "<?php echo post_permalink( $sp->ID ); ?>"
},
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, you are trying to create a file .JSON is that right ? If yes, try to create a PhP Array, and then convert it to JSON using [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Comment: Stage all data in a buffer, then `rtrim(',', $buffer);`

Comment: Do **NOT** build json manually. json_encode() takes care of everything for you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your array is well formed (has indexes starting from zero) you can put it at the beginning, skipping the first record:

```
<?php foreach( $speaker_posts as $idx => $sp ): ?>
<?php if ($idx) echo ","; ?>
{
    "@type" : "person",
    "name" : "<?php the_field('name_title', $sp->ID); ?>",
    "sameAs" : "<?php echo post_permalink( $sp->ID ); ?>"
}
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Otherwise you need an external counter:

```
<?php $idx = 0; foreach( $speaker_posts as $sp ): ?>
<?php if ($idx++) echo ","; ?>
{
    "@type" : "person",
    "name" : "<?php the_field('name_title', $sp->ID); ?>",
    "sameAs" : "<?php echo post_permalink( $sp->ID ); ?>"
}
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: @johnnyr209 It won't when there's a `"` in `name_title`, though.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're apparently outputting JSON, use PHP to do it.

```
<?php

$json = [];

foreach($speaker_posts as $sp) {
    $json[] = [
        '@type' => 'person',
        'name' => get_field('name_title', $sp->ID),
        'sameAs' => post_permalink( $sp->ID ),
    ];
}

print json_encode($json);

?>
```

Side note: this will save you from potentially unsafe characters like quotation marks / apostrophes in the field/permalink contents.